# Adding missing dates in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot

I want to show pivot chart for the defects logged in ClearQuest. I am creating pivot table based on the data. Obviously the charts shows only dates on which defects are logged.

It does not plot the dates on which no defect is logged.

How can I add such row with 0 value in pivot table. Please note that that date will not have any source data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind messing with your Pivot Table structure:

- Create the Pivot Table with your dates in the 'Rows' field
- Right-click on the dates and click 'Group'
- Select 'years', 'months' and 'days'
- Click 'OK'.

Now right-click on the dates again and click 'Field Settings' - 'Layout & Print' and check 'Show items with no data'.

[image: Group items as below]
If you're still struggling, there are more pictures here http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/display-missing-dates-in-excel-pivottables